# Need about Angular and mySQL

Tags: mysql, angular

I have a homework:

> Create Angular app: like reaction on Facebook, it get data from mySQL
>   and show the number of click.

[image: Illustrating images]

So my question:

How to get data from mySQL and show it when I clicked on the heart? (Not need update back to mySQL)

Answer (score -1):

You can not connect mysql to angular app, as angular is frontend javascript framework which do not have facility to connect to db system.

You need some backend technology to talk with database like php, nodejs, java or something else..

Create rest api in some technology like nodejs and use it to get facebook likes from db